# Navigating to preference fragment using navigation component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to migrate my medium sized app to the new Android `navigation` component.

Currently, my app consists of the `single activity` and I'm planning on keeping it the same (for that matter); So, I'm facing this issue in which I have a settings fragment (`PreferenceFragment`) that can be navigated to, basically, from every other fragment. 
This navigation is made through a menu in the app bar, therefore `onOptionsItemSelected` (containing this navigation) is in the main activity.

[image: Navigation graph]

I'm having trouble figuring what is the right way to connect the `settingsFragment` to the other ones.
Connecting it to all others seems like spaghetti to me.

1. Should `settingsFragment` be connected to all another fragment?
2. Should I abandon the single activity application architecture since Google isn't giving enough reasons (or any reasons) to support it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To deal with your problem, you can use `global actions`.
To use them you need to define action inside `<navigation>` tag, not inside `<fragment>` as  you usually do.
Your nav graph will contain the next code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!--Your other fragments-->

    
    <!--Settings fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.oleksii.stackoverflow.SettingsFragment"/>

    <!--Global action-->
    <action android:id="@+id/open_settings_fragment"
        app:destination="@id/settingsFragment"/>
</navigation>
```

In the graph editor it will be displayed in the next way (just arrow in the left of `destination`):

[image]

More details: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-global-action

Comment: if i had multiple graph and need to use a global action, how to access it from other fragments?

Comment: Why do I get an error: **ID does not reference a View inside this Activity**?

Comment: The OP's link now redirects to this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action (pasting it in case the old link becomes out of date some day)

Answer (score 6):

I can navigate to another fragment or preference fragment using following approach:

Global Settings Fragment:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    app:title="@string/global_settings_header">
    <Preference
        app:key="fragment_a"
        app:title="A"
        app:fragment="....settings.SettingsFragmentA" />
    <Preference
        app:key="fragment_b"
        app:title="B"
        app:fragment=".....settings.SettingsFragmentB" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Implemented `PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback` in activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback {
....

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceStartFragment(PreferenceFragmentCompat caller, Preference pref) {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    if (pref.getKey().equals("fragment_a")) {
        navController.navigate(R.id.nav_settings_fragment_a);
    } else if (pref.getKey().equals("fragment_b")) {
        navController.navigate(R.id.nav_settings_fragment_b);
    }
    return true;
}

....
}
```

I can also navigate to any fragment that is defined in the navigation graph using NavController.

Any fragment can be used in `app:fragment=".....settings.SettingsFragment"`. The idea is to trigger the `onPreferenceStartFragment` callback.

Answer (score 5):

but if your preferences are hierarchical you get `Fragment <insert fragment name here> declared target fragment <guid> that does not belong to this FragmentManager!` when you click on a child preference.

i have not found a solution to this yet.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: override getCallbackFragment and implement onPreferenceStartFragmentCallback, there you have to do your custom fragment starting e.g. with navController

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305040/preferencefragments-not-in-the-same-fragmentmanager

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer from @Alexey, to invoke the global action, you can use code like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.settingsFragment);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```