# Can we use Android Jetpack Navigation Component with Settings preferences?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, android-jetpack-navigation

Is it possible to use Android Jetpack Navigation Component to navigate the fragments of a Settings Preferences? I have a Settings screens with multiple nested Preference Fragments. I was wondering if it is feasible to use Android Jetpack Navigation Component to facilitate my task?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029821/navigating-to-preference-fragment-using-navigation-component

Comment: Na, i want to navigate to nested fragments WITHIN my settings activity using Navigation component.

Answer (score 6):

The google documentation states that hierarchical nesting of preferences are now deprecated in favour of inter-fragment navigation; that is the structure `<PreferencesScreen> ... <PreferencesScreen ...> ... </PreferenceScreen> ... </PreferenceScreen>` is now out.

The documents propose that one replace the nested `<PreferenceScreen/>` with a preference and set the `app:fragment` attribute, hence

```
<xml ...>
<PreferencesScreen ...>
    <Preference
        android:title="Title"
        app:fragment="TLD.DOMAIN.PACKAGE.preferences.SUBPreferenceFragment"
        app:destination="@+id/SUBPreferenceFragment" # Not supported by Schema
        android:summary="Summary"/> 
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Note :** *It'd be mighty handy if they allowed `app:destination="@+id/SUBPreferenceFragment"` to identify the navigation destination; I simply duplicate `app:destination` from the navigation graph's XML file.*

From the documentation it is then possible to navigate between the `PREFERENCEFramgent`s by referencing this `preference.fragment` as follows

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity(),
                  // Preferences Interface
                  PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback
{
    ...
    override fun onPreferenceStartFragment(caller: PreferenceFragmentCompat, preference: Preference): Boolean 
    {
        // Instantiate the new Fragment
        val args = preference.extras
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            classLoader,
            preference.fragment)
        fragment.arguments = args
        fragment.setTargetFragment(caller, 0)
        // Replace the existing Fragment with the new Fragment
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.FRAGMENT, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
       return true
    }
    ...
}
```

There is however a small Snafoo ! `R.id.FRAGMENT` in a normal activity represents the placeholder within the activities' view where one would swap the main fragments in an out of existence. When using Navigation `R.id.FRAGMENT` maps to `R.id.NAVIGATION` and the code above swaps out the entire navigation fragment with the preference. For an activity using Navigation a reformulation is necessary.

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity(),
                  // Preferences Interface
                  PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback
{
    ...
    override fun onPreferenceStartFragment(caller: PreferenceFragmentCompat, preference: Preference): Boolean {
        // Retrieve the navigation controller
        val navctrl = findNavController(R.id.navigation)
        // Identify the Navigation Destination
        val navDestination = navctrl.graph.find { target -> preference.fragment.endsWith(target.label?:"") } 
        // Navigate to the desired destination
        navDestination?.let { target -> navctrl.navigate(target.id) }
    }
    ...
}
```

While this works I am a bit dubious about the line that determines the `navDestination`. If you have a better incantation for `val navDestination = navctrl.graph.find { target -> preference.fragment.endsWith(target.label?:"") }` then please edit the question or leave a comment accordingly so I can update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Navigation components inside Preference fragments.

I have also a main preference fragment with multiple nested fragments. For me the best way was to navigate just inside preference fragments without any activity. So I created onPreferenceClickListeners and navigate just like you would from a normal fragment.

```
findPreference(getString(R.string.PREF_GN_BUTTON_MAIN)).setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference5 -> {
            Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(R.id.another_settings_fragment);
            return true;
        });
```

The advantage of this way is that you can use gradle plugin [Safe args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) to navigate between destinations. So it is a little bit safer than to use it only with ids just like [Carel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57564776/9317258) from Activity.

I tried to override `onPreferenceStartFragment` in my activity but I could not see any advantages of it. I use single Activity architecture.