# Using NavController with preferences

Tags: android, androidx, android-navigation

I'm currently migrating my application to androidX and the new navigation component. My app has different settings screens which are nested into each other. Before androidX the `PreferenceScreen` were nested into each other. Now days this is handled as:

```
<Preference
    app:fragment="com.example.SyncFragment"
    .../>
```

So in XML we give an absolute class name for the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` we want to show by clicking on that preference. The fragment transaction has to be implemented by the Activity, which holds the fragments. I would love to do this by my `NavControler` but here is my problem:

```
override fun onPreferenceStartFragment(caller: PreferenceFragmentCompat, pref: Preference): Boolean {
    val nav = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    nav.navigate(<Fragment ID>) // Only int IDs can be passed here
    return true
}
```

Is there any way I could give the `pref` reference, which I get through this callback, an ID so I can handle the fragment transaction with the `NavControler`? Or do I over complicate things here and have missed something?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that you want your specific ```PreferenceFragmentCompat``` to be available as  navigation graph destination?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60903243/3751576 might help.